# Set background color of active tab bar item in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar

I'm hoping to accomplish this without the use of images, if at all possible. Is there a way to create the effect shown in the image programmatically without have to render each tab out as an image?

Every question I've reviewed on SO has the tabs saved as JPGs, which is more work than I feel it should be.

Any ideas?[image: Tab Bar]

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I took a similar approach to @matcartmill but without the need for a special image. **This solution is just based on your color.**

```
// set red as selected background color
let numberOfItems = CGFloat(tabBar.items!.count)
let tabBarItemSize = CGSize(width: tabBar.frame.width / numberOfItems, height: tabBar.frame.height)
tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage = UIImage.imageWithColor(color: UIColor.red, size: tabBarItemSize).resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets.zero)

// remove default border
tabBar.frame.size.width = self.view.frame.width + 4
tabBar.frame.origin.x = -2
```

I'm making use of the following extension of `UIImage`:

```
extension UIImage {

    class func imageWithColor(color: UIColor, size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        let rect: CGRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
        color.setFill()
        UIRectFill(rect)
        let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }

}
```

I hope this helps!

## for swift 4

```
extension UIImage {

   class func imageWithColor(color: UIColor, size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    let rect: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
    color.setFill()
    UIRectFill(rect)
    let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
   }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! I actually just had to use this method again so I came back to this post. This is easily the best way to do it that I've seen.

Comment: Its not working for iPhone 7s but working for iPhone 5s why?

Comment: @schickling this was good until iOS 11 /xcode 9. any ideas how make it fit the whole item like it was before iOS 11?

Answer (score 10):

Update to **SWIFT 3:**

```
let numberOfItems = CGFloat((tabBarController?.tabBar.items!.count)!)

let tabBarItemSize = CGSize(width: (tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.width)! / numberOfItems,
                            height: (tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.height)!)

tabBarController?.tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage
    = UIImage.imageWithColor(color: UIColor.black,
                             size: tabBarItemSize).resizableImage(withCapInsets: .zero)

tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.size.width = self.view.frame.width + 4
tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.origin.x = -2

extension UIImage
{
    class func imageWithColor(color: UIColor, size: CGSize) -> UIImage
    {
        let rect: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
        color.setFill()
        UIRectFill(rect)
        let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's not working in ios 11. @ynamao did get any solution?

Answer (score 3):

So here's what I ended up doing. It's a mix of using a 640x49 PNG that's the color of the blue "highlighted" background I need.

In AppDelegate.swift:

```
var selectedBG = UIImage(named:"tab-selected-full")?.resizableImageWithCapInsets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0))
UITabBar.appearance().selectionIndicatorImage = selectedBG
```

And then in the first View Controller that gets loaded, I have:

```
tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.size.width = self.view.frame.width+4
tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.origin.x = -2
```

The reason for the  above two lines is that, by default, Apple has a 2px  border between the left and right sides of the tab bar and the tab bar items.

In the above I simply make the tab bar 4px wider, and then offset it so the border on the left falls just outside of the view, thus the border on the right will also fall outside of the view.

Comment: `UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)` is equivalent to `UIEdgeInsetsZero` I believe.