# Setting background colour of active tab - swift

Tags: swift, uitabbar

I've been attempting to customise the background colour of the active tab, via [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29045147/set-background-color-of-active-tab-bar-item-in-swift). It works pretty well, but I get a very odd 1px line on each of the tabs when they're selected - this only occurs when I start the app in portrait mode and then turn it landscape.

Am I missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing this by adjusting the selectionIndicatorImage code, to generate an image that was 2x as wide as the current tab. I realise this probably isn't the best solution, so if anybody has a better one please do let me know!

The line of code:

```
let tabBarItemSize = CGSize(width: (tabBar.frame.width*2) / numberOfItems, height: tabBar.frame.height)
```