# How to change the TabBarItem background color

Tags: ios, swift, tabbar, uitabbaritem

I'm trying to change the background of a **TabBarItem** or to make a whole Image which take all the space.

Like the example below :

[image: Tabbar]

Do You have an Idea how to do that in swift

Comment: You can look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30041127/ios-8-tab-bar-item-background-colour

Comment: And that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31117069/changing-tab-bar-item-image-and-text-color-ios

Comment: Check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/a/40717556/2714877

Answer (score 0):

Swift:

```
//change icon and title color
UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.redColor()

//change background default color
UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()

//change selected background image
UITabBar.appearance().selectionIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "tabSelected")
```

Answer (score 0):

in `swift 4.2` with `iOS 12.1`

```
func setUpSelectionIndicatorImage(withColors colors: [UIColor]) {
    //Make selection indicator image from color and set it to tabbar
    let singleTabWidth: CGFloat = self.tabBar.frame.size.width / CGFloat(self.tabBar.items?.count ?? 1)
    let height = DeviceType.IS_IPHONE_X ? 55 : self.tabBar.frame.size.height
    let singleTabSize = CGSize(width:singleTabWidth , height: height)
    let edgeInsets = DeviceType.IS_IPHONE_X ? UIEdgeInsets(top: 1, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0) : .zero
    self.tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage = UIImage.gradient(size: singleTabSize, colors: colors)?.resizableImage(withCapInsets: edgeInsets)
}

 override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    let colors = [UIColor.white, UIColor.green]
    setUpSelectionIndicatorImage(withColors: colors)
}
```